Using Langchain ChatOpenAI functionality with LiteLLM
I have initially written two functions to provide me with a model and function calling directly from OpenAI. Here is the complete code:
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

def get_open_ai(temperature=0, model='gpt-4'):

    llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model=model,
    temperature = temperature,
)
    return llm

def get_open_ai_json(temperature=0, model='gpt-4'):
    llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model=model,
    temperature = temperature,
    model_kwargs={"response_format": {"type": "json_object"}},
)
    return llm

The problem is I now need to use LiteLLM as a proxy, which I am forwarding to a local port, for example localhost:3005. I know I should have an option somewhere to put an openai_base = "localhost:3005" or something similar, to make my code hit the LiteLLM gateway instead of OpenAI directly, but this does not work in my above code. I also looked at the LiteLLM documentation which gives an example with the OpenAI library not with the Langchain wraper. Could anyone please tell me what I must change in my code to make it work with my own LiteLLM server ?

I believe the parameter you're looking for is base_url:
llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model=model,
    temperature = temperature,
    base_url='localhost:3005' # might need to try with 127.0.0.1:3005
)

More info here
